# VPN protection against DDoS

Tags: vpn, ddos

I am thinking of getting a VON, for DDoS protection and other various things, though what if an attacker knows my real IP already?

Comment: If an attacker knows your real IP, then they can flood your connection, regardless of your use of a VPN.